# Gvmd and postgresql: how to solve this error?

Tags: gvmd, openvas

System is Debian 12 port for ppc64 (sid).
I have installed and configured gvmd, the problem is: is impossible to update the SCAP database cause of this error.

All seems ok.·

```
tail -15 /var/log/gvm/gvmd.log
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h01.09 UTC:1220: Updating CPEs
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h14.50 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2012.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h15.15 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2019.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h17.25 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2017.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h18.21 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2006.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h18.42 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2010.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h19.07 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2020.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h20.42 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2013.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h21.10 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2003.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h21.14 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2008.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h21.44 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2022.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h23.45 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2002.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h24.00 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2007.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h24.18 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2005.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h24.35 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2021.xml
```

but...

```
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h30.25 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2015.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h30.53 UTC:1220: Updating /var/lib/gvm/scap-data/nvdcve-2.0-2023.xml
md manage:   INFO:2023-11-13 15h32.16 UTC:1220: Updating CVSS scores and CVE counts for CPEs
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.18 UTC:1220: sql_exec_internal: PQexec failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
 (7)
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.18 UTC:1220: sql_exec_internal: SQL: UPDATE scap2.cpes SET (severity, cve_refs)       = (WITH affected_cves          AS (SELECT cve FROM scap2.affected_products              WHERE cpe=cpes.id)          SELECT (SELECT max (severity) FROM scap2.cves                  WHERE id IN (SELECT cve FROM affected_cves)),                 (SELECT count (*) FROM affected_cves));
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.18 UTC:1220: sqlv: sql_exec_internal failed
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.21 utc:1011: sql_exec_internal: PQexec failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
 (7)
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.21 utc:1011: sql_exec_internal: SQL: BEGIN;
md manage:WARNING:2023-11-13 15h32.21 utc:1011: sqlv: sql_exec_internal failed
md   main:MESSAGE:2023-11-13 15h32.22 utc:6301:    Greenbone Vulnerability Manager version 22.4.2 (DB revision 250)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks